# Displaying methods of the wshNetwork object

Tags: powershell

I need to create a variable to represent the wshNetwork object.  Using this variable I need to display all the methods that this object supports, and only display these methods?  Any suggestions?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
New-Object -ComObject Wscript.Network | Get-Member -MemberType Method
```